# Best practice for creating combined Azure Cognitive Search index from multiple SQL tables with change detection

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cognitive-search

I have the following tables in a Azure SQL Database:

```
Tags (tagId int PK, tagLabel nvarchar(100))
Entities (entityID int PK, ....)
EntityTags (entityId int FK, tagID int FK)
```

I need fast retrieval of *Entities* from a fast growing db based on *tagLabel* searches (fully or partially specified) and I thought instead of querying the db, I would use Azure Cognitive Search service to retrieve the data from an index containing *entityId* as key and a comma separated list of *tagLabel*s. as another field.

I could create a SQL view as source for the index, but I learnt that choosing this option I will not have change detection.

Is there a way to update a view based index regularly (every ~10 mins) without recreating it or any other best practice to create the index for this scenario?

Comment: How many tables you have? You should be able to create a built-in indexer per SQL table (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers) pointing to a single index. Built-in indexers do have support for single table view change detection. Multiple indexers pointing to a single index is supported. Indexer limit per service SKU is listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, no.

What you can do is write your own 'data change detector' that will only push data to Azure Cognitive Search index when needed. Also, use MergeOrUpload operation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.search.documents.models.indexdocumentsaction.mergeorupload?view=azure-dotnet#azure-search-documents-models-indexdocumentsaction-mergeorupload-1(-0)

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid that is the case.

Comment: That's what I've been doing for the past few years :D